Sufficient condition for integrability
Let $f : (a,b)\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Is is integrable, in general? What if the domain was $[a,b]$? If it's only generally integrable in the second case, is it because of uniform continuity?
My counterexample for the first case was a function like
$$f(x) = \tan\left(\frac\pi{b-a}x-\frac{\pi(a+b)}{2(b-a)}\right)$$
which diverges as $x\to a^+$ or $x\to b^-$. On the other hand, if the domain is $[a,b]$, aka. compact, then the range is also compact and therefore limited, because of the Heine-Borel theorem. Thus, since $f$ is continuous by hypothesis, it has no singularities within its domain and it's Riemann integrable.
Is my line of reasoning correct?

and it's Riemann integrable --- Typically, Riemann integrability (for real-valued functions of a real variable) is only defined when the domain is an interval of the form $[a,b]$ where $-\infty < a < b < \infty,$ and when dealing with a domain that is an open interval, one then considers an improper integral defined in terms of a limit of Riemann integrals.

The Heine-Cantor theorem states:

Let $(M,d_M)$ and $(N,d_N)$ be metric spaces and let $f : M \to N$ be a continuous mapping between the two. If $M$ is compact, then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

By the Heine-Borel theorem, a compact set in $\mathbb R$ is closed and bounded. Thus, a function defined over a closed interval $[a,b]$ is uniformly continuous.
Finally, it isn't hard to prove that uniform continuity implies integrability.
